# Haml now supports tabs, can we make the haml editor support tabs?

Tags: eclipse, editor, haml

HAML used to require 2 spaces for indentation.  However, it now supports tabs.  I'm using RadRails under eclipse, and it does not allow me to configure HAML editor to use tabs like the other editors.  Is there a way to override that through a config file, or can we get an update to the HAML editor to allow tabs?